# Return rows based off specific date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below sample data.

How can I return the correct rows depending on the date?

For example, if the date is :

20th August - only record IDs 2 and 4 would return

2nd August - only record IDs 1 and 3 would return

8th August - only record IDs 1 and 2 would return

15th July - only record IDs 3 would return

```
Create table #temp
(
    ID int,
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime NULL
)

insert into #temp
(
    ID,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
)
select
    1,
    '01 Aug 2019',
    '12 Aug 2019'
union all
select
    2,
    '04 Aug 2019',
    NULL
union all
select
    3,
    '01 Jul 2019',
    '03 Aug 2019'
union all
select
    4,
    '14 Aug 2019',
    NULL
```

Comment: I hope there will come a day when I won't feel the need to upvote an SQL question that supplies proper sample data, but it is not this day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean) way to do it:

```
SELECT ID,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM #temp
WHERE StartDate <= @SearchDate
AND (EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate > @SearchDate)
```

Comment: Hi Zohar, 3 different answers with 3 different methods. Yours and mkRabbani's return the same result. Any reason why there's a difference in method there?

Comment: mkRabbani's condition is a bit too cumbersome IMHO - note he has `@DT >= StartDate` twice in his code. Shivani's answer is much the same as my own, only difference is that I use an exclusive condition for the `EndDate` and Shivani is using an inclusive condition (`>` vs `<=` with opposite directions)

Comment: Thanks Zohar, appreciate the help and reply. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below logic-

```
DECLARE @DT DATE = '20190802'

SELECT * FROM #temp
WHERE (@DT>= StartDate AND @DT <= EndDate)
OR  (EndDate IS NULL AND @DT >= StartDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from #temp
where @searchdt >= StartDate 
    and (@searchdt <= EndDate OR EndDate is null)
```